# Affine Transformation Matrix Counterclockwise 90°

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I used the search function but couldnt quite find the answer to my problem.
I need the general Affine Transformation matrix coefficient for a counterclockwise rotation.
My Problem is that i found different matrix explanations for a positive rotation on different sites (can link if needed), but there are two different ones and i need to know which one is the positive rotation one.
The 2 i found:
(cos(alpha)   sin(alpha))
(-sin(alpha)  cos(alpha))

and

(cos(alpha)  -sin(alpha))
(sin(alpha)   cos(alpha))

From what ive read and used so far, i would say and thought that the first one is for positive rotation and the second one for negative (counterclockwise) rotation. Can anyone confirm that?

Comment: Try applying the transformation to a few points, and see what happens. This isn't meant to be a dismissive answer. Choosing the correct matrix depends on how you're going to use it to transform points, and only you know that.

Comment: i will link you the 2 sites i meant
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getRotateInstance(double)

http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/affine.htm

in general one of them should be for positive and one for negative rotation

Comment: Specifically, try transforming the point $(1,0)$. Where does it go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one a clockwise rotation and the second one is an anticlockwise rotation.

Which we call positive or negative matters on how you define angles. In mathematics we usually define $0^\circ$ as the positive x-axis and have angles increase as you go towards the positive y-axis. So for this definition the first would be a negative rotation and the second a positive rotation.

However sometimes it is suitable to define north as $0^\circ$ and increase through positive values towards east. This gives the opposite means for positive and negative rotations.

As such I tend to avoid labelling them as 'positive' or 'negative' and instead refer to 'clockwise' and 'anticlockwise'.

Comment: perfect answer and good explanation, thank you very much :)

Comment: This may or may not be correct.Choosing the right matrix depends on how you are going to use it to transform points. There are two common ways.

Answer (score 0):

A 90 degree CCW rotation will move the point $(x,y)$ to the point $(-y,x)$.

See if you can find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $(x,y)A = (-y, x)$.

Or alternatively, see if you can find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ such that $B(x,y)^T = (-y, x)^T$.

You will get two different answers.

So, finding the correct matrix depends on how you are going to use it to transform points. There are two common ways:

1. You consider your point coordinates to be a row vector, and you multiply by your matrix on the right (vector $\times$ matrix). This is what people in computer graphics generally do, for example.
2. You consider your point coordinates to be a column vector, and you multiply by your matrix on the left (matrix $\times$ vector). This is what mathematicians like to do, typically.